# MaxEnt Model Equivalance and Disjunction

Tags: maximum-entropy

I want to use a maxent model for quite a simple problem but it doesn't behave as I expect. I'm clearly not understanding.

I have two sets of labels $L = \{A,B\}$ and $L' = \{A',B'\}$ and some relationship that holds between them $\Theta = \{Equals, Disjoint\}$. I have data of the form $<l,l',\theta>$ where $l \in L, l' \in L'$ and $\theta \in \Theta$. I want to know for a new pair from $L$ and $L'$ whether they belong to $Equals$ or $Disjoint$. Given only the evidence that $<A, A', Equals>, <A, B', Disjoint>$ and $<B, A', Disjoint>$. I look at the class probability and it is the following:

```
A A' Equals[0.9656]  Disjoint[0.0344]
A B' Equals[0.0294]  Disjoint[0.9706]
B A' Equals[0.0294]  Disjoint[0.9706]
B B' Equals[0.0000]  Disjoint[1.0000]
```

According to the OpenNLP [maxent](http://maxent.sourceforge.net/about.html) model that uses generalised iterative scaling. The first three lines are as expected but the final line should just be uncertain i.e  Equals[0.5]  Disjoint[0.5] as there is no information about how B and B' relate to each other. Instead it seems to have associated B with class Disjoint from evidence $<B,A',Disjoint>$ and attributed it to the unseen B, B' data.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another modelling technique that I should use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping the data points into a single context gives the desired result:

```
AA' Equals[0.9902]  Disjoint[0.0098]
AB' Equals[0.0098]  Disjoint[0.9902]
BA' Equals[0.0098]  Disjoint[0.9902]
BB' Equals[0.5000]  Disjoint[0.5000]
```

This way, evidence of class membership is not shared between events.